# beaker InvalidCryptoBackendError: No AES library is installed error

Tags: python, macos, aes, beaker

HI i get following error for beaker on Mac os x sno leopard 10.6.8

```
InvalidCryptoBackendError: No AES library is installed, can't generate encrypted cookie-only Session
```

What's the workaround or fix for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is very simple . pycrypto python library was missing.

```
pip install pycrypto
```